# How to determine if my task was accepted by thread pool and not rejected?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have `ThreadPoolExecutorService`, with core pool size 5 and max pool size 10. Also i have set queue size to 0. So when i try to `submit` 11 tasks - the last one is rejected. For these case i am using `RejectedExecutionHandler`. However, from submitter thread i can not determine - my task is submitted or rejected. 
Here is code from submitter thread:

```
public void submitToAsyncExecution(Runnable r) {
  Future<Void> task = this.threadPool.submit(r)
  //is it possible to use returned future object to find out if my task is rejected or not ? 
}
```

I know - alternative is to omit `RejectedExecutionHandler` and let rejection exception to be throw, however handler approach is more reasonable in my case.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly, you want the code that is using the `Future` to receive the `RejectedExecutionException` and handle it, instead of the code calling `submitToAsyncExecution`.

I can offer you the following:

```
public static Future<?> submitToAsyncExecution(Runnable r) {
    final ExecutorService s;
    try {
        return s.submit(r);
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        final CompletableFuture<Void> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
        // You can wrap it or create another exception if needed.
        cf.completeExceptionally(e);
        return cf;
    }
}
```

It catches the exception and creates a Future from it. Every piece of code using it will receive the exception from the rejection and deal with it.